# calling information from the database for user

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to call only the logged in users information. So far nothing comes up, Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "megan", "megan") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("megan") or die(mysql_error()); 

$id = $_SESSION['id_user']; //Get user's ID 
Print $id; //Test
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user='" . $id . "'") 
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

echo "Your user name is: <br>"; 
echo $row['username'];
```

?>

Updated code with sugestions but still doesnt work

If i put in Select * from user the entire database comes up, not the user that is logged in

Comment: Don't use mysql_* statements. Prefer using PDO or even mysqli statements.

Comment: @user1491556 what does Print $id return ?

Comment: session_start(); must be the first line at your php code. And don't use print, use echo instead.

Comment: I agree with @tsabz here - php.net says that `mysql_*` is deprecated and will eventually be discontinued. Also - this is screaming **mysql injection**. Make sure to `mysql_real_escape string` or the `PDO_MySQL` or `MySQLi_*` equivalents.

Comment: nothing with moving session_start. and I was testing the variable would print to screen hence Print $id

Comment: @tsabz and Scott S: this isn't the question sense, just give an answer and don't enter in a deprecated commands discussion. It still works even depprecated.

Comment: i am unfamiliar with mysql_real... and have never used PDO and MySQLi

Comment: Have you checked your web server log files for errors?

Comment: @elvenbyte There's no discussion here. Just saying that he'd better use prepared statements instead of the mysql_* commands. There's no debate about it. If I was the OP, I'd prefer someone who try to guide me through a better solution, if there is one, instead of someone who just let me use an old-fashion way.

Comment: not sure where to look for these types of errors...

Comment: Change the select * to select [column names] to makes sure you are hitting the correct DB and column names.  Could be something overly simple.  I also think it's time to set up a sqlfiddle.

Comment: how do i set up a sqlfiddle? tried pulling the id_user from the database and cant do that

Answer (score 1):

Try this line. I believe your query string is not correct and you are not querying using your user id's value, but instead using the string '$id'.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user='{$id}'");
```

Comment: still nothing comes up, just blank screen

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it this way:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user=" . $id);
```

And if $id is not numeric but a string...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user='" . $id . "'");
```

Of course, you can also make an or die(mysql_error()) at the end of the line.

Comment: did you change the position of session_start() to the beggining of file?

Comment: try to change all the sql sentence to uppercase, and also de field inside $row['username']; (so it will come $row['USERNAME'];). Do not touch the variable $id

Comment: when i change user to uppercase i get this error" Table 'megan.USER' doesn't exist", when I change it back to lower i still get nothing

Comment: Mmm..., could you change the table name to other than user? MySQL already got a "user" table... Perhaps...

Comment: Have you tried with mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Answer (score 0):

Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
$sql = "SELECT `username` FROM user WHERE id_user = '$id' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

list($username) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

var_dump( $username ); // for test
```

Comment: I put this in but all that returns is NULL

Comment: try the sql code in phpmyadmin query with your id and check the result

Comment: I copied the SELECT above and returned: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). Not working. but when i put a specific number in like 7 it works

Comment: so you don't have any result in your table for this id. the problem is not depend on your code. check your code with the row id that you sure have result in your table

Comment: if i put SELECT `username` FROM user WHERE id_user = '$id' in the table i get nothing. If i put SELECT `username` FROM user WHERE id_user = 7 it returns the information